# Browse spring context

Tags: spring, context.xml

Currently, I'm working on a project which has a large number of dependencies.
During development, I sometimes have issue with some spring bean.
Normally, the stack trace can tell me the name of the bean. However, it does not shows me which context.xml file declares the bean. Moreover, it does not tell me which .jar file contains the context file and how that context file is imported into my project (I means the chain of import).

As there are many depedencies, not all context file are uses, many beans are override....
It takes me a lot of time to search the correct context file. One simple solution is to import all related project into my eclipse workspace and everything becomes horribly slow.

I'm thinking about writing a tools to speed up the process:

Given a name of spring bean / the class of bean, the tool will search in the whole class path of application and returns:

- The spring context file which declares the bean.
- The .jar file that contains the spring context file.
- Extract the content spring context file and show it directly to user
- If user provides the root spring context file, the tool will shows the import chain to the destination spring context file.

It does not take lots of time to implement this but I just wonder whether somebody has already implement it? I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I found the project https://github.com/julior/spring-inspector. It's interesting, but it's not what I need.

If you know a tool like the one above, I'd be very happy to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You totally should look at Intellij IDEA's great support for Spring Framework.

More information available here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/spring_framework.html

To find interesting bean in xml config you just need to click on green bean image.

[image]

Intellij IDEA is definitely worth its price.